# How to get logged in username in views.py in django

Tags: python, html, django, authentication, oauth

Actually i'am very new to django and python. In /templates/home.html, added **{{ user.username }}** it's showing currently logged in username

```
<p>Welcome {{ user.username }} !!!</p>
```

I want to get currently logged in username in **views.py** file. How to get username?

i tried different way but i am not get the result

1. `user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)`
2. `username = request.GET['username']`
3. `def sample_view(request):
           current_user = request.user
           print(current_user)`

Please tell me, How to achieve my result.

my views.py look like this. is there any problem on my views.py

```
    #!python
    #log/views.py
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.template import Context
    from contextlib import contextmanager
    # Create your views here.
    # this login required decorator is to not allow to any
    # view without authenticating
    @login_required(login_url="login/")
    def home(request):
         return render(request,"home.html")
#dummy_user = {{ username }}
#user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
#username = request.GET['username']
#print(usernam
#user = request.user
#print(user)

    def sample_view(request):
            current_user = {}
            #current_user['loggeduser'] = request.user
             #or
            current_user['loggeduser'] = request.user.username
            return render(request,"home.html",current_user)
           # print(current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 10):

Provided that you have enabled the [authentication middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware), you don't need to do any of this. The fact that the username shows up in your template indicates that you have enabled it. Each view has access to a `request.user` that is an instance of a `User` model. So the following is very much redundant

```
user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
```

Because you already have `request.user.username`!! if you wanted to find the user's email, you do `request.user.email` Or just do

```
user = request.user
```

and use the newly created variable (eg user.username)

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user

> From the AuthenticationMiddleware: An instance of AUTH_USER_MODEL
>   representing the currently logged-in user. If the user isn’t currently
>   logged in, user will be set to an instance of AnonymousUser. You can
>   tell them apart with is_authenticated, like so:

Comment: i am getting NameError: name 'User' is not defined

Comment: Which means you have not read my answer. What I said is that you don't need to do `user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)`

Comment: you are kidding right? request is part of the method signature of a view

Comment: sorry, i really don't know python and django. I added my views.py code. Please check that code and tell me the problem of my views.py code.

Comment: cearly your method signature defines request `def sample_view(request):` so that error you mentioned is absolutely impossible.

Comment: ^^ this comment is epic!